# How to display base64 image on html without putting all the big base64 string in my html?

Tags: flask, base64, jinja2

I have generated my base64 string from my image and assigned it to : session['graph']

When I have this code, it works:

```
 <pre>
       <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAHgCAYA 
       ..... " /> 
</pre>
```

This works as well:

```
def graph():
    d=base64 string
    return '<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s" width="640" height="480" border="0"/>' %(d)
```

But I want use jinja for dynamic display of my images and graphs.
Using jina,  this code is not working: can you help me to fix it please? thanks

```
 <pre>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{session['graph']}}" /> 

 <pre>
```

or this one is also not working in html file:

```
  <p> 
'<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s" width="640" height="480" border="0"/>' %(d)
</p>
```

Comment: I found it out!  In fact nothing is wrong with above code.
 I had not added the 'graph=graph' input into my app.py file :)))). Thanks every body.

Answer (score 1):

It might worth checking for `{{seession['graph']}}` not to accidentally include `data:image/png;base64` part. Exactly my recent issue in a similar case

Comment: Hey Evgeny, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit your answer to remove the question? Or in case you prefer this to be answered by Jasper, you could move the discussion into the comments to the original question.

Comment: Thanks, Nick! Done